# Android broadcast attivity no history

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, history

I have a problem with an activity started by BroadcastReceiver.

I use this activity for overwrite default lockscreen and I would like the activity is not mapped from the stack.

I try with various flag as: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK... but all of these not work.

Receiver.java

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.lockscreen" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name="com.app.AppActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  android:launchMode="singleTop" android:noHistory="true">

        <intent-filter >
            <!-- <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> --> 
            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    <service android:name="com.app.MyService" android:noHistory="true">
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="receiver.Receiver" android:noHistory="true">     

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />            
        </intent-filter>                        
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just modify your activity's launch mode like this

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.test"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
         >
</activity>
```

or you can use `android:launchMode="**singleTask**"'

**"singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack.**

**The difference between them:**

The "singleTask" and "singleInstance" modes also differ from each other in only one respect: A "singleTask" activity allows other activities to be part of its task. It's always at the root of its task, but other activities (necessarily "standard" and "singleTop" activities) can be launched into that task. A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task.

as described here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode